# Not sure what I'm doing wrong with this Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

So, I'm working on an HTML based site using Image maps and I've created some in-line DIV's with buttons working.

I've been creating a second area that should launch Jquery to hide/show forms inside of a button, but For some reason the scripts do not work when launched via `<script src="Domain.tld/script.js"></script>`
But they do work when launched DIRECTLY into the code via `<script>` Code here `</script>`
Below is the non working version to see the buttons you must click the THIRD button on the page.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cronusdevelopment.github.io/IMVU/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cronusdevelopment.github.io/IMVU/shop.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cronusdevelopment.github.io/IMVU/frame.js"></script>
<script src="https://cronusdevelopment.github.io/IMVU/shop.js"></script>
<style>
  table.imvuolstatuss {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
        font-size: 25px;
    margin-left: 424px;
    margin-top: -799px;
}</style>
<div id="content_container">
  <div id="home">
    <br /><br />
    <p style="color: white;">HERE CONTENT FOR home</p>
  </div>
  <div id="about">
    <br /><br />
    <p style="color: white;">HERE CONTENT FOR about</p>
  </div>
  <div id="shop">
    <br /><br />
    <p style="color: white;">
    <button id = "BtMale" class="ShopButtons">Male</button>
<button id = "BtFemale" class="ShopButtons">Female</button>
<button id = "BtFurn" class="ShopButtons">Room/Furn</button>
<button id = "BtOther" class="ShopButtons">Other</button>
<button id = "BtAll" class="ShopButtons" onclick=window.open("https://www.imvu.com/shop/web_search.php?manufacturers_id=196067881")>Whole Shop</button>
<form id="M" hidden>
   <br>
   <select name="categories_id" onChange="window.open('http://www.imvu.com/shop/web_search.php?cat='+this.form.categories_id.value+'&manufacturers_id=196067881&sort=id&sortorder=desc','','scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, status=1,toolbar=1, location=1, menubar=1');">
      <option value="" selected>Choose Something</option>
      <option value="41">Clothing for Male</option>
      <option value="71">&nbsp;Male Accessories</option>
      <option value="70">&nbsp;Male Bottoms</option>
      <option value="316">&nbsp;Male Bundles</option>
      <option value="92">&nbsp;Male Eyebrows</option>
      <option value="91">&nbsp;Male Eyes</option>
      <option value="98">&nbsp;Male Gloves</option>
      <option value="67">&nbsp;Male Hairstyles</option>
      <option value="296">&nbsp;Male Heads</option>
      <option value="102">&nbsp;Male Shoes</option>
      <option value="68">&nbsp;Male Skintones</option>
      <option value="69">&nbsp;Male Tops</option>
      <option value="3088-3091">&nbsp;Male Outfits </option>
   </select>
</form>
<form id="F" hidden>
 <br>
   <select name="categories_id" onChange="window.open('http://www.imvu.com/shop/web_search.php?cat='+this.form.categories_id.value+'&manufacturers_id=196067881&sort=id&sortorder=desc','','scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, status=1,toolbar=1, location=1, menubar=1');">
      <option value="" selected>Choose Something</option>
      <option value="40">Clothing for Female</option>
      <option value="153">&nbsp;Female Accessories</option>
      <option value="78">&nbsp;Female Bottoms</option>
      <option value="324">&nbsp;Female Bundles</option>
      <option value="90">&nbsp;Female Eyebrows</option>
      <option value="89">&nbsp;Female Eyes</option>
      <option value="97">&nbsp;Female Gloves</option>
      <option value="75">&nbsp;Female Hairstyles</option>
      <option value="295">&nbsp;Female Heads</option>
      <option value="101">&nbsp;Female Shoes</option>
      <option value="76">&nbsp;Female Skintones</option>
      <option value="128">&nbsp;Female Tops</option>
      <option value="3088-3090">&nbsp;Female Outfits</option>
   </select>
</form>
<form id="Rooms" hidden>
<br>
   <select name="categories_id" onChange="window.open('http://www.imvu.com/shop/web_search.php?cat='+this.form.categories_id.value+'&manufacturers_id=196067881&sort=id&sortorder=desc','','scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, status=1,toolbar=1, location=1, menubar=1');">
      <option value="" selected>Choose Something</option>
      <option value="107">Rooms & Furniture</option>
      <option value="1027">&nbsp;Furniture</option>
      <option value="366">&nbsp;Rooms</option>
      <option value="1279">&nbsp;Furniture Bundles</option>
      <option value="2386">&nbsp;Furnished Rooms</option>
      <option value="107-1027-1552">&nbsp;Posing Spots</option>
      <option value="107-1027-1905">&nbsp;Animated Pose Spots</option>
   </select>
</form>
<form id="Other" hidden>
<br>
   <select name="categories_id" onChange="window.open('http://www.imvu.com/shop/web_search.php?cat='+this.form.categories_id.value+'&manufacturers_id=196067881&sort=id&sortorder=desc','','scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, status=1,toolbar=1, location=1, menubar=1');">
      <option value="" selected>Choose Something</option>
      <option value="108">Avatars</option>
      <option value="425">Pets</option>
      <option value="495">Stickers</option>
   </select>
</form>
</p>
  </div>
  <div id="shout">
    <br /><br />
    <p style="color: white;">HERE CONTENT FOR shout</p>
  </div>
  <div id="honor">
    <br /><br />
    <p style="color: white;">HERE CONTENT FOR honor</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="layout-container">
  <img
    src="https://i.imgur.com/vc0zoBl.png"
    width="1013"
    height="1300"
    border="0"
    usemap="#map"
  />
  <map name="map">
    <area
      shape="rect"
      coords="273,740,356,768"
      onclick="changeframe('home','frame1')"
    />
    <area
      shape="rect"
      coords="360,740,445,768"
      onclick="changeframe('about','frame1')"
    />
    <area
      shape="rect"
      coords="450,740,535,768"
      onclick="changeframe('shop','frame1')"
    />
    <area
      shape="rect"
      coords="539,740,624,768"
      onclick="changeframe('shout','frame1')"
    />
    <area
      shape="rect"
      coords="630,740,715,768"
      onclick="changeframe('honor','frame1')"
    />
  </map>
  <div id="frame1" class="box"></div>
  <script>
    changeframe("home", "frame1");
  </script>
</div>
<div id="OLStatus">
  <table class="imvuolstatuss">
     <tr>
        <td align='center'>Status - <img src="https://gaf210.gafcodes.com/get_online_status?u=196067881&offline=https%3A%2F%2Fuserimages01.imvu.com%2Fproductdata%2Fstickers_af13a170f917065f15d41a7d6a484f37.gif&online=https%3A%2F%2Favatars.imvu.com%2Fcatalog%2Fweb_images%2Fmy_page%2Fonline_under_image.gif&unknown=https%3A%2F%2Favatars.imvu.com%2Fcatalog%2Fweb_images%2Fmy_page%2Fspace.gif" alt=""></td>
     </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

below is the working version.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cronusdevelopment.github.io/IMVU/shop.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <div id="shop">
    <br /><br />
    <p style="color: white;">
    <button id = "BtMale" class="ShopButtons">Male</button>
<button id = "BtFemale" class="ShopButtons">Female</button>
<button id = "BtFurn" class="ShopButtons">Room/Furn</button>
<button id = "BtOther" class="ShopButtons">Other</button>
<!--DO NOT UNTAG THIS AS IT'S NOT NEEDED YET.-->
<!--<button id = "BtAll" class="ShopButtons" onclick=window.open("https://www.imvu.com/shop/web_search.php?manufacturers_id=196067881")>Whole Shop</button>-->
<form id="M" hidden>
   <br>
   <select name="categories_id" onChange="window.open('http://www.imvu.com/shop/web_search.php?cat='+this.form.categories_id.value+'&manufacturers_id=196067881&sort=id&sortorder=desc','','scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, status=1,toolbar=1, location=1, menubar=1');">
      <option value="" selected>Choose Something</option>
      <option value="41">Clothing for Male</option>
      <option value="71">&nbsp;Male Accessories</option>
      <option value="70">&nbsp;Male Bottoms</option>
      <option value="316">&nbsp;Male Bundles</option>
      <option value="92">&nbsp;Male Eyebrows</option>
      <option value="91">&nbsp;Male Eyes</option>
      <option value="98">&nbsp;Male Gloves</option>
      <option value="67">&nbsp;Male Hairstyles</option>
      <option value="296">&nbsp;Male Heads</option>
      <option value="102">&nbsp;Male Shoes</option>
      <option value="68">&nbsp;Male Skintones</option>
      <option value="69">&nbsp;Male Tops</option>
      <option value="3088-3091">&nbsp;Male Outfits </option>
   </select>
</form>
<form id="F" hidden>
 <br>
   <select name="categories_id" onChange="window.open('http://www.imvu.com/shop/web_search.php?cat='+this.form.categories_id.value+'&manufacturers_id=196067881&sort=id&sortorder=desc','','scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, status=1,toolbar=1, location=1, menubar=1');">
      <option value="" selected>Choose Something</option>
      <option value="40">Clothing for Female</option>
      <option value="153">&nbsp;Female Accessories</option>
      <option value="78">&nbsp;Female Bottoms</option>
      <option value="324">&nbsp;Female Bundles</option>
      <option value="90">&nbsp;Female Eyebrows</option>
      <option value="89">&nbsp;Female Eyes</option>
      <option value="97">&nbsp;Female Gloves</option>
      <option value="75">&nbsp;Female Hairstyles</option>
      <option value="295">&nbsp;Female Heads</option>
      <option value="101">&nbsp;Female Shoes</option>
      <option value="76">&nbsp;Female Skintones</option>
      <option value="128">&nbsp;Female Tops</option>
      <option value="3088-3090">&nbsp;Female Outfits</option>
   </select>
</form>
<form id="Rooms" hidden>
<br>
   <select name="categories_id" onChange="window.open('http://www.imvu.com/shop/web_search.php?cat='+this.form.categories_id.value+'&manufacturers_id=196067881&sort=id&sortorder=desc','','scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, status=1,toolbar=1, location=1, menubar=1');">
      <option value="" selected>Choose Something</option>
      <option value="107">Rooms & Furniture</option>
      <option value="1027">&nbsp;Furniture</option>
      <option value="366">&nbsp;Rooms</option>
      <option value="1279">&nbsp;Furniture Bundles</option>
      <option value="2386">&nbsp;Furnished Rooms</option>
      <option value="107-1027-1552">&nbsp;Posing Spots</option>
      <option value="107-1027-1905">&nbsp;Animated Pose Spots</option>
   </select>
</form>
<form id="Other" hidden>
<br>
   <select name="categories_id" onChange="window.open('http://www.imvu.com/shop/web_search.php?cat='+this.form.categories_id.value+'&manufacturers_id=196067881&sort=id&sortorder=desc','','scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, status=1,toolbar=1, location=1, menubar=1');">
      <option value="" selected>Choose Something</option>
      <option value="108">Avatars</option>
      <option value="425">Pets</option>
      <option value="495">Stickers</option>
   </select>
</form>
</p>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cronusdevelopment.github.io/IMVU/shop.js"></script>
```

below is the Javascript/Jquery for the above.

```html
$('#BtMale').on('click', function(e){

    $("#M").toggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('Male');
    if ($("#BtFemale").is(":enabled"))
            $("#BtFemale").prop("disabled",true);
             else
            $("#BtFemale").prop("disabled",false); 
            
        if ($("#BtFurn").is(":enabled"))
            $("#BtFurn").prop("disabled",true);
             else
            $("#BtFurn").prop("disabled",false);

        if ($("#BtOther").is(":enabled"))
            $("#BtOther").prop("disabled",true);
             else
            $("#BtOther").prop("disabled",false);
});
$('#BtFemale').on('click', function(e){

    $("#F").toggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('Female');
        if ($("#BtMale").is(":enabled"))
            $("#BtMale").prop("disabled",true);
             else
            $("#BtMale").prop("disabled",false);
 
        if ($("#BtFurn").is(":enabled"))
            $("#BtFurn").prop("disabled",true);
             else
            $("#BtFurn").prop("disabled",false);

        if ($("#BtOther").is(":enabled"))
            $("#BtOther").prop("disabled",true);
             else
            $("#BtOther").prop("disabled",false);
   
});
$('#BtFurn').on('click', function(e){

    $("#Rooms").toggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('Rooms');
        if ($("#BtMale").is(":enabled"))
            $("#BtMale").prop("disabled",true);
             else
            $("#BtMale").prop("disabled",false);

        if ($("#BtFemale").is(":enabled"))
            $("#BtFemale").prop("disabled",true);
             else
            $("#BtFemale").prop("disabled",false);

        if ($("#BtOther").is(":enabled"))
            $("#BtOther").prop("disabled",true);
             else
            $("#BtOther").prop("disabled",false);
   
});
$('#BtOther').on('click', function(e){

    $("#Other").toggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('Other');
        if ($("#BtMale").is(":enabled"))
            $("#BtMale").prop("disabled",true);
             else
            $("#BtMale").prop("disabled",false);

        if ($("#BtFemale").is(":enabled"))
            $("#BtFemale").prop("disabled",true);
             else
            $("#BtFemale").prop("disabled",false);

        if ($("#BtFurn").is(":enabled"))
            $("#BtFurn").prop("disabled",true);
             else
            $("#BtFurn").prop("disabled",false);
   
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide the relevant code in the question. Questions should be self contained and we shouldn't have to go off site just to review your initial issue. Having to go through a whole repo is not how things work here. Take a few minutes to thoroughly read [mcve]

Comment: Thanks for that, I believe I've fixed it enough?

Comment: You need to wrap the jQuery code in `$(function(){ /* code here */})` when script tag is in `<head>` because the elements don't exist yet in the `<body>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Comment: This did NOT answer my question, however I did use your code , and that still seemed to have not worked for me. The code is within my shop.js

Comment: Ok any errors thrown in browser dev tools console?

Comment: Not a single error.

Comment: Include the script on the bottom of the page, the element you are binding is undefined at that point.

Comment: I've now wrapped the script into the bottom of the entire index.html, still not working, but producing no errors.

Comment: I figure if I can't get this done, I suppose I could just do regular Javascript, but how would I wrap an AND statement into an IF statement if the two aren't of the same type.

Comment: Is the file even being loaded? Check in your browser dev tools network to be sure

Comment: I've checked on several different browsers, and each one does show that it's being loaded.